# How to render backslash without new lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a string in javascript like `var Value = "\\\\192.168.0.1\\\\Dir\\NewDir\\Imp\\file.xml"`,

but the output is (with new lines):

```
\\\\192.168.0.1
\\\\Dir
\\NewDir
\\Imp
\\file.xml


form.setValues({
 'idInput' : Value
});
```

form - is a form created in extJs.
idInput - is the id of display field
Value - is the new value on a displayfield

How to keep the backslashes without the new lines? I tried with JSON stringify, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you getting that output?  Post your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: please use the "edit" button to update your question with extra code and information. It's important info and doesn't belong just in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Check now the description.

Comment: you must create a fiddle, that will help us better to understand your issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that - you want to render value with backslases as it is:

```
var Value = '\\\\192.168.0.1\\\\Dir\\NewDir\\Imp\\file.xml';
Value = encodeURI(Value);
Value = decodeURI(Value.replace(/%5C/g, "%5C%5C"));
```

Take a look on example : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/301t

Comment: It doesn't work
I think is a problem with width after set new value

Comment: Yes, it's problem with width - you neet to set new width there